# What is causing DispatchServlet.doDispatch(...) to throw an exception?

Tags: spring, jackson

I am making a REST call using the REST template to call from my UI WAR to my SVC WAR. I am able to pull the DTO from the database and send it from my SVC-side controller w/ the @ResponseBody tags, but I end up getting a 500 error on the UI side. With a bit of debugging, the class/method DispatchServlet.doDispatch(...) is throwing a "NoClassDefFoundError". I have posted the view from my debugger. The DTO I am sending consists of a list of Row DTOs. I am using BigDecimal, Date, and an Enum type, but outside that I only have Strings or lists of them. There are other controllers using the same similar combinations. What could be different here.
[image: Debugger view when exception is being thrown.]
To clarify here are the log messages being shown:

UI:

77198 [http-8080-4] WARN  org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate  - GET request for "[URL]" resulted in 500 (Internal Server Error); invoking error handler

Service:

DEBUG com.hcsc.services.controller.DataController - getInfoRows - start

DEBUG com.hcsc.services.controller.DataController - getInfoRows - end

Comment: Posting a screenshot isn't really helpful, post the actual stack trace and that should also tell you which class it is missing.

Comment: That is the problem. I have my controller confirming that it has returned it's value as in the Logger.debug("Method END") displaying. This happens AFTER I return the DTO from the controller mapping. The only error I see after that without going into debug mode is the 500 error code on the UI app.

Comment: The fact that your controller functions correctly doesn't mean everything before (or after depends on how you look at it) works correctly. A CNFE will show up in one of your logs somewhere.